# JavaScript Array.copyWithin method

Tags: javascript

When I use `Array.prototype.copyWithin` method:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].copyWithin(-3,0,-1);
```

Output is

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

How are the numbers 1, 2, 3 added to the output result?

Comment: what is your expecting output?

Comment: i'm expecting [1,2,1,4,5]

Comment: @GuruDeepak question is, why do you expect that to be the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have

```
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].copyWithin(-3, 0, -1); // [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
```

What you do

> ```
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]         values
>  0  1  2  3  4          indices from start
> -5 -4 -3 -2 -1          indices from end
>  ^     ^     ^          needed indices
>  |     |     +--------  end
>  |     +--------------  target      
>  +--------------------  start
>  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]        given array
>  [      1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  copied values
>  [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]        result array, keeping the same length
> ```

You need to change the start and end values.

Basically you have 4 possibillities, either to get the indices from the start or from the end.

> ```
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  values
>  0  1  2  3  4   indices from start
> -5 -4 -3 -2 -1   indices from end
>  ^  ^  ^         needed indices
>  |  |  +-------  target      
>  |  +----------  end
>  +-------------  start
> ```

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].copyWithin(2, 0, 1).join(', '));
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].copyWithin(2, -5, -4).join(', '));
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].copyWithin(-3, 0, 1).join(', '));
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].copyWithin(-3, -5, -4).join(', '));
```

Comment: In this [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].copyWithin(-3,0,-1); target is -3 and start is 0 and end is -1 rite? so output should be [1,2,1,4,5] rite?

Comment: right, but the end does not matter if the array is smaller than the needed amount of items, who are between start and end.

Comment: i'm confused actually

Comment: can you please explain me

Comment: See this example [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].copyWithin(-3,-1,-4);
output :[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] it should be [1,2,5,4,3] rite?

Comment: it is not possible to change the order of the items to reverse

Answer (score 1):

Your Target is -3 ([1,2,**3**,4,5]), this is where the copy begins.
Your Start is 0 ([**1**,2,3,4,5]), this is the Start of the sequence you want to copy.
Your End is -1 ([1,2,3,4,**5**]), this is where your sequence ends.

So you are putting 1,2,3,4,5 into your array starting from index 2 (value 3).

Because copywithin doesn't alter the length of the array you get 1,2,1,2,3

If you want 1,2,1,4,5 you will have to use `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].copyWithin(-3,0,-4);`

Comment: **So you are putting 1,2,3,4,5 into your array starting from index 2 (value 3).** i did'nt get this part

Comment: You have misconstrued target, it's where the copy is placed. The second parameter is where to start from, so the copy is placed after the 2 and consists of 1 to 4 inclusive. But since the length isn't altered, the copy is truncated at the 5th index.

Comment: For some reason, I found this answer easier to digest and comprehend than the answer with a really nice ascii diagram. And I am a sucker for ascii diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the negative index the results are correct. Read more here

[Array.prototype.copyWithin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin?v=example)

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4,5].copyWithin(2, 0, 1))
```

Comment: needs an explanations

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Turns out someone else did exactly that already. I will have to delete my answer, even though I was the first to answer correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To get [1,2,1,4,5] do 
`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].copyWithin(2,0,1)`

```js
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].copyWithin(2,0,1));
```

**Explanation of copyWithin**

array.copyWithin(target, start, end)

**target**: Required. The index position to copy the elements to,

**start**: The index position to start copying elements from,

**end**: Optional. The index position to stop copying elements from (default is array.length)

*In your case change should start from third position (that is index = 2), so **target = 2**, and start copying from first position, so **start = 0**, only one element need to copy. So end at index = 1, that means **end = 1***

have a look at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin?v=example)

Comment: I answered the same 2 minutes before.

Comment: @arboreal84 You want me to delete my answer?

Comment: Just a consideration for the OP.

Comment: Note that *start* is also optional (defaults to 0). ;-)

Comment: @RobG Ohh yeah. Absolutely. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to simplify how the copyWithin() method works using a few examples.

```
const myArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U"];
let output = myArray.copyWithin(4,2,5); //A,B,C,D,C,D,E,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U
```

from picture it is clear that end parameter

- is optional (default is till end) and
- if specified then end is not included.

[image]

Based on the above explanation we can derive a solution for your question as below.

[image]